# Variable importance plot using randomforest package in R

Tags: r, variables, random-forest

I created a `random forest model` and now want to look at the variable importance. While trying to do so, it only shows the `MeanDecreaseGini` plot, not the `MeanDecreaseAccuracy` plot. If I try to specify `type = 1`, it gives an error saying

> Error in imp[, i] : subscript out of bounds

but the same doesn't happen with `type = 2`.

The code I used is:

```
RF_Model<- randomForest(as.factor(Ash )~B1+B2+B3+B4+B5+B6+B7+B8+B9+B10+B11+B12+B13+B14+B15
                        +B16+B17+B18+B19+B20, data=Subset, ntree=2000, Importance=TRUE)
print(RF_Model)
Important=RF_Model$importance
View( Important).
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `importance=TRUE` instead of `Importance=TRUE`. Please, see below for reproducible example:

```
rf = randomForest(Species ~ .,data=iris,Importance=TRUE)
importance(rf,type=1)

Sepal.Length
Sepal.Width 
Petal.Length
Petal.Width 

rf = randomForest(Species ~ .,data=iris,importance=TRUE)
importance(rf,type=1)
             MeanDecreaseAccuracy
Sepal.Length            10.035280
Sepal.Width              4.849584
Petal.Length            32.512948
Petal.Width             34.386394
```